# Shortcut for Windows Explorer to jump to the last folder in the folder-file-list? Autohotkey

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I am searching for a shortcut to jump to the last folder in Windows Explorer (ignoring the files following).

Example:

[image: example windows explorer]

Here I want to jump to folder `2022-09` without typing in "2022-09". I am searching for a key combination.

The folder and file names are arbitrary. Giving the answer to hit `g` and then cursor up (according to the screenshot) is not valid.

I guess we need an Autohotkey script for this. If so, what would the script look like?

Comment: If you sort by date descending, it would be the first.

Comment: As I said, please do not take the example as a fixed problem. Arbitrary files, arbitrary folders, arbitrary time stamps. Looking for a **key combination / shortcut**. Like Shift CTRL END.

Comment: Add "Folder" column. Set AHK to click folder column, then press Home key to go to first file, then click folder column again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this AHK script:

```
; Press F1 in the active explorer window to jump to the last folder in the folder-file-list

#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass ; Explorer

    F1:: 
        last_folder := ""
        ExplorerPath := GetActiveExplorerPath()
        Loop, Files, %ExplorerPath%\*, D ; only folders
            last_folder := A_LoopFileName
        If (last_folder = "")
            MsgBox, No folders in`n%A_Tab%"%ExplorerPath%"
        else
            SelectExplorerItem(last_folder) 
    return

#IfWinActive

GetActiveExplorerPath() { ; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=69925
    explorerHwnd := WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
    if (explorerHwnd)
    {
        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        {
            if (window.hwnd==explorerHwnd)
            {
                return window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
            }
        }
    }
}

SelectExplorerItem(ItemName) { ; selects the specified item in the active explorer window, if present
   ; SelectItem -> msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774047(v=vs.85).aspx
    explorerHwnd := ""
    explorerHwnd := WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
    if (explorerHwnd)
    {
        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        {
            try  if (window.hwnd==explorerHwnd)
            {
                If (Item := Window.Document.Folder.ParseName(ItemName))
                        Window.Document.SelectItem(Item, 29)
                Return (Item ? True : False)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the last folder, no matter the order in which the files
are sorted (as long as folders are first), I suggest the simple method
of going down the items in the list and stopping on the last folder.

This AutoHotKey script will do that with the hotkey <kbd>F10</kbd> :

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass

F10::
Send, {Home}
Sleep, 5
last=
loop {
    file = % Explorer_GetSelection()
    isfolder = % InStr(FileExist(file),"D")
    if !isfolder or file==last
        break
    last = % file
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 5
}
if !isfolder
    Send, {Up}

Explorer_GetSelection(hwnd="") {
    hwnd := hwnd ? hwnd : WinExist("A")
    WinGetClass class, ahk_id %hwnd%
    for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        if (window.hwnd==hwnd)
            sel := window.Document.SelectedItems
    for item in sel
        ToReturn .= item.path "`n"
    return Trim(ToReturn,"`n")
}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I selected the other answer as best because it jumps directly to the file. With your solution I have to wait until the cursor moved down folder by folder until it reaches the file.

Comment: The other answer didn't work for me on my sort order, which is why I added mine.

Comment: Thanks in any case. Seeing different approaches always helps! 